# Different lyings

Tags: the-buddha, five-precepts, teaching, metta

Here are my questions:

> Can lying be nonverbal? like in action?
>
> Is cheating lying?
>
> Is writing the wrong answer when you know the correct answer lying?
>
> Is skipping the line cheating, and in a sense lying?
>
> If I break a promise, is that lying or in anyway kammically bad?

Answer (score 1):

Can lying be nonverbal? like in action? Strict Buddhist sense "Yes" But there are conditioned to be fulfilled.

Is cheating lying?I would say yes.

Is writing the wrong answer when you know the correct answer lying?I would say yes

Is skipping the line cheating, and in a sense lying?I would say yes

If I break a promise, is that lying or in anyway kammically bad? I would say yes